# python script for a REST APi, using json, with curl works

Tags: python, json, rest, curl

I want to do a python script for a REST API, first  authenticate and then do either a get or a put,  usually a do it using curl as follows:

```
curl -i -X POST -d username=admin -d password='pass' -c ./cookies.txt http://ip_address:9080/nbapiemswsweb/login 
curl -v -i -H “Content-Type:application/json” -X GET -b ./cookies.txt 'http://ip_address:9080/nbapiemswsweb/rest/v1/Search/Element'
```

I am trying to get authenticated, but I am getting 401, and then don't know how to do a GET:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import json

url = "http://IP_ADDRESS:9080/nbapiemswsweb/login"

myResponse = requests.post(url,auth=HTTPDigestAuth(raw_input("username: "), raw_input("Password: ")), verify=True)
print (myResponse.status_code)
```

result

```
python restapi.py
username: admin
Password: pass
401
```

I need to get 200 and be able to do a get for the second curl

Comment: Why are you setting the `Content-Type` header for the curl `GET` request (the second)? A GET request has no request body, so setting a content type makes no sense there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your curl command just posts a username and password as *form data*, not as a Authorization header.

Do the same with `requests`, and use a [session object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) to handle the capture and sending of cookies:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    formdata = {
        'username': raw_input("username: "),
        'password': raw_input("Password: "),
    }
    myResponse = session.post(url, data=formdata, verify=True)

    second_response = session.get('http://IP_ADDRESS:9080/nbapiemswsweb/rest/v1/Search/Element')
```

Comment: Thanks, That work, I add the print for the respond and the content, Do you know how can I add user and password with no form, without asking for the credentials,the credentials will be on the script

Comment: @JVJ: the username and password are just strings, store them in the dictionary instead of using `raw_input()` calls. I only put those in because your code did.